# Consistency/range conditions for (integral) transform mapping into higher-dimensional space

Tags: reference-request, integral-transforms

I am interested in learning more about what the (formal) implications are when transforming a $n$-dimensional function space (e.g., the space of all $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$) to a higherdimensional one (say, $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$, $m>n$); in particular, in terms of consistency or range conditions (is there a difference?).

A real example could be the relationship between the result of the X-ray transform and John's equation. A dummy example could involve the operator $\mathcal{D}$ such that $g(x,y):=(\mathcal{D}f)(x,y) = f(x)$ -- clearly, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0$ is the (only?) range/consistency condition in that case.

I am thus looking for very general results such as "if we map from a space of dimension $n$ to one of dimension $m$, we find $m-n$ consistency equations". Also, results about 'requiredness' and 'sufficiency' are of interest.

What may be useful literature suitable for a non-professional mathematician to get an overview of this topic and confirm some hypotheses that I derived from particular examples (such as the related question, [Range conditions on a linear operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028695/range-conditions-on-a-linear-operator))

Comment: I've been thinking about this off and on for a while and it's not at all obvious that one can say anything particularly general, though I could be wrong.  The most promising lead I've found is [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970269?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) paper by Hormander on the range of a convolution-type operator (which necessarily maps into a space with the *same* underlying dimension).  I'll post a full answer if I come up with anything more complete.